# Add a new visual webpart

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-part, solution

I have added a new Visual web part in an already deployed solution.

The new webart is not appearing in SharePoint Designer under `All files` folder.

How to up[ate the existing solution with the newly added visual webpart?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the visual webpart is in the package in your visual studio project.

Update the solution with this command

```
Update-SPSolution -Identity contoso_solution.wsp -LiteralPath c:\contoso_solution_v2.wsp -GACDeployment
```

If the webpart is still not there, reactivate the feature or reinstall the feature.